# How to create a base thread class to run method async with thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, runnable

I want to create Base class to send any function to it to call with a thread.
Base on AsyncTask functionality, I can't use that because I will call a thread in another thread not only from Main Activity.
here is my sample code 
in

**Android**:

```
public class BaseThread {
    public static Thread call(Function threadMethod)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                threadMethod();
            }
        };
        thread.start();
        return thread;
    }
    public static Thread Call(Function threadMethod, Object parameter)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(threadMethod);
        thread.start();
        return thread;
    }
    public static void sleep(int millisecondsTimeout)
    {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(millisecondsTimeout);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex)
        {
           ///TODO Handle Exception and Logging
        }
    }
}
```

example in **c#**:

```
internal class BaseThread
{
    public static Thread Call(ThreadStart threadMethod)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(threadMethod);
        thread.Start();
        return thread;
    }
    public static Thread Call(ParameterizedThreadStart threadMethod, object parameter)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(threadMethod);
        thread.Start(parameter);
        return thread;
    }
    public static void Sleep(int millisecondsTimeout)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(millisecondsTimeout);
    }
}
```

which type of variable should set in method instead of this line :

```
call(Function threadMethod)
```

And whats best practice instead of this base class?

Answer (score 0):

Actually Thread can be considered as a "base thread class" because you can achieve such behavior with putting Runnable/Callable implementation into constructor. Put logic into run method of runnable. But I highly recommend you not to use pure threads and take a look at ExecutorService. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Android has a very handy class HandlerThread. You can make your custom thread and publish Runnables to it. It has a embedded queue of Messages, every one of which is handler sequentially.